# running rsync in crontab with keys

Tags: ssh, cron, rsync

I am having issues running rysnc in my crontab. It's my own users's crontab so it runs as my user, and I've set up passwordless rsa keys. When I run the rsync job on my shell console, it works. But when I import it into crontab, it says it ran in /var/log/syslog, but I don't see the folder synced.

My crontab is super simple:

```
* * * * * rsync -av --delete myuser@mybox:/home/backup/ /home/backup
```

I believe crontab is not picking up my user's environment. if I do the following, I can see only some environment variables:

```
* * * * * env >> /tmp/my_env_variables
```

This outputs as `cat /tmp/my_env_variables`

```
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
HOME=/home/myuser
LOGNAME=myuser
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/sh
PWD=/home/myuser
```

I don't have env variables such as:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-uapL7nIOVj/agent.103170
```

What's the right way to import the env variables I need in cron?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. This is barely on topic at best. You should consider asking this on [unix.se] or [su] instead of here.

Answer (score 0):

From `man 5 crontab`:

> An active line in a crontab is either an environment setting or a cron command.  An environment setting is of the form:
>
> ```
> name = value
> ```

However, requiring an SSH agent to be always present when a cron-job runs is going to be unreliable. If you want this to work you're going to need a pass-phrase-less key set up. You can restrict that key, in `authorized_keys` on the server, to only work from a specific IP address.